# How a value can be of type integer, double & num at the same time?

Tags: class, dart, types, casting

I have the following expression:

```dart
const value = 10 / 2;
```

In VS Code, if I hover over `value`, it shows me its type is `double`, which makes sense. But if I run the following lines of code, they all evaluate to `true`:

```dart
print(value is num); // true
print(value is double); // true
print(value is int); // true
```

`num` is the super class, and `double` & `int` are sibling classes. How come a value be of the sibling type & the super type simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compiling for the web, and running in a browser.
DartPad does that for you, and you get the same effect if you compile your program using the web compilers (dart2js or the dev-compiler).

When compiling Dart for the web, all numbers are compiled to JavaScript numbers, because that's the only way to get efficient execution.

JavaScript does not have integers as a separate type. All JavaScript numbers are  IEEE-754 double precision floating point numbers, what Dart calls `double`s.

So, when you have a number like `10 / 2`, which would create a `double` in native Dart, it creates the JavaScript number 5.0 on the web. So does the integer literal `5`. There is only one "5" number in the browser, so both integer and double computations create the same number.

To make that be consistent with the type system, it means that "5" is a value which implements both the `int` and the `double` interface. A fractional value like `5.5` only implements `double`.

When running natively, integers and doubles are separate types.

This is all [described in the Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers#dart-number-representation).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import 'dart:io';
 
void main() {
    const value = 10 / 2;
    print(value is num); // true
    print(value is double); // true
    print(value is int); // true
}
```

The output is:

> true
> true
> false

That is expected result.

[image]

Comment: Would you please explain how does `import 'dart:io'` impact it?

Comment: The result is same without importing dart:io

Comment: My bad: I was running the code here: https://dartpad.dev/dart Maybe, it's something to do with it. I tried it console, and it prints `value is int` as `false`.

Comment: Please check other online executors such as [jdoodle Online Dart IDE](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-dart-online/)